# Get a count of grouped by rows that match certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that in essencwe looks like this:

```
╔═════════╦═══════╦══════╗
║ Balance ║ Limit ║ Type ║
╠═════════╬═══════╬══════╣
║    6    ║   2   ║   1  ║
║    3    ║   3   ║   2  ║
║    2    ║   5   ║   2  ║
╚═════════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

Now, what I want to do is to count Balance, grouped by Type and then return the count of "offending" types. That is, if it has an aggregate Balance that is not higher than the highest present Limit for that type.

So in the above example (looking at Limit and Type, which is a fixed structure:

The Balance in row 1 needs to be at least 3 and the sum of balances in rows 2 and 3 needs to be at least 6.

Thus, I want my query to return a 1 (indicating that there is one Type whose summed balance is too low).

Of course, if the table is empty, I want a zero returned.

How can I achieve this? I did something similar earlier, but without having to group by Type. Thus I could do it as:

```
SELECT Rowcount = COUNT(IIF (Balance - Limit < 1, 1, NULL)) FROM Table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need to get your maximum limit per type:

```
SELECT  Balance,
        Limit = MAX(Limit) OVER(PARTITION BY Type),
        Type
FROM    [Table];
```

Then you can use this maximum limit in your count, unfortunately you can't place the windowed function inside the `COUNT` so you will need to use a subquery, then only count distinct types:

```
SELECT  [RowCount] = COUNT(DISTINCT Type)
FROM    (   SELECT  Balance,
                    Limit = MAX(Limit) OVER(PARTITION BY Type),
                    Type
            FROM    [Table]
        ) AS t
WHERE   Balance <= Limit;
```

You also may as well just move the criteria since to the `WHERE` since you are not performing any other counts.

---

**EDIT**

I may have over complicated this. You can group by `type` in a subquery to get the maximum limit, and the sum of the balance, then count the results of this subquery:

```
SELECT  [RowCount] = COUNT(Type)
FROM    (   SELECT  Balance = SUM(Balance),
                    Limit = MAX(Limit),
                    Type
            FROM    [Table]
            GROUP BY Type
        ) AS t
WHERE   Balance <= Limit;
```

Or:

```
SELECT  [RowCount] = COUNT(Type)
FROM    (   SELECT  Type
            FROM    [Table]
            GROUP BY Type
            HAVING SUM(Balance) <= MAX(Limit)
        ) AS t
```

Comment: This seems to almost be what I'm after. But it does not seem to add up the Balance for rows with the same Type. That is, if I have two rows of data: (Balance: 5, Limit: 2, Type: 1) and (Balance: 3, Limit: 4, Type: 1) it returns a 1. Pressumably because the balance of the second row is under the limit for row 2. (I want to compare 5 + 3 to 4 in this example).

Answer (score 0):

May be this query helps:

```
SELECT COUNT(Type) AS types_with_too_low_balances_count
FROM (
  SELECT Type
    FROM table_name
    GROUP BY Type
    HAVING SUM(Balance) <= MAX(Limit)
) a
```

Test it on [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47f59/1)

Comment: Hmm, this seems to always return a 0.

Comment: Added test on SQL Fiddle, it returns `1` with your data